# Can I make active devices share voltage equally using ad hoc shunt resistors?

Tags: scr, leakage-current, active-components

I have 3 active devices in series, SCRs in this case but I'm guessing that's not important. Each is rated for 2.4 kV. The total voltage I will actually apply is 6.6 kV.

Leakage current is guaranteed to be 80 mA maximum, but the datasheet does not give a typical value. At 2.2 kV per device, that suggests that each device's off resistance can be as low as 25 kohms. 6.6 kV * 0.08 A ~= 500 W, which for the application is a lot. Putting 2.5 kohm resistors in parallel to force equal sharing is out of the question because the 5 kW it would burn is way too high.

I figure the device that eats up the most voltage also has the lowest leakage. Therefore, if any one device eats up enough voltage that it would be out of specification at full voltage, I ought to be able to put a shunt resistor in parallel with that device so that it is in specification.

Note that, in a string of three devices, only one or at most two of them will get a shunt resistor. That is what makes this network a bit unorthodox. It's also completely ad hoc. Every example I've seen of using resistors to achieve equal voltage sharing used identical smaller resistors conducting at least 10x more current than device leakage. I can't do that because it would eat up my entire power budget.

My question is this:

If I do this, is the resulting shunt resistor likely to be valid for several years? Will most SCRs keep the same leakage current provided they are not abused?

Edit: What this question is really about is the stability of an SCR's leakage current. If you measure it in the factory, does it stay relatively stable over the life of the device? Or is it prone to go up and down?

Comment: i'm not sure whether anyone will guarantee you that an unorthodox solution will last with 6600 volts for several years

Comment: Less than one tenth headroom may be a bit close.

Comment: @user253751 What I am really asking about is the stability of leakage current in active devices, specifically SCRs.

Comment: @greybeard can you tell me a bit more?

Comment: For a sum of rated voltages of 7.2 kV, a nominal voltage of 6.6 kV is what I call uncomfortably close: consider 10% over-voltage, and the split being uneven about 15%. For leakage current, take a somewhat comprehensive datasheet and look for graphs involving it, and table entries stating both min and max.

Comment: @greybeard sorry for the delayed reply. I am trying to find out if I measure leakage as 10 mA (or whatever) at the factory, is leakage likely to stay roughly the same for at least 2 years?

Comment: "Everything has been said, if not by everyone (yet)." Basics of [Series Connection of SCR and Voltage Equalization](https://electricalbaba.com/series-connection-scr/)

Comment: @greybeard Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure how this article speaks to the time stability of leakage current. Another way to ask the question is, "Are the statistics of SCR leakage current stationary?"

Comment: And my take is: Why bother where I expect things like temperature and variance of instance parameters to dominate? While I wouldn't know about [ageing of semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_aging) beyond [Arrhenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_operating_life#Acceleration_factor_(AF)), I expect device/specimen history (has seen non-destructive ESD, breakdowns with limited current - you name it) to play a significant role.

Comment: (Search for SCR "leakage current drift".)